# How to save uploaded file and then return that with GAE?

Tags: google-app-engine, memcached, google-cloud-datastore, blobstore

I need to create the following application with GAE usage:

1. User uploads some file (let's say POST that to myapp.appspot.com/upload);
2. I need to save that (in datastore?) and return the link;
3. Based on the link provided user should be able to download the file within next 5 minutes.

I've created the following:

**app.yaml**

```
application: synoext
version: 1
runtime: python
api_version: 1

handlers:
- url: /upload
  script: synoext.py

- url: /file/\w+
  script: synoext.py

- url: /cleanup
  script: synoext.py
```

**synoext.py**

```py
import datetime
import logging
import urlparse

from google.appengine.ext import webapp
from google.appengine.ext.webapp.util import run_wsgi_app
from google.appengine.ext import db
from google.appengine.api import urlfetch

class Files(db.Model):
    file = db.BlobProperty()
    added = db.DateTimeProperty(auto_now_add=True)  

class UploadFile(webapp.RequestHandler):
    def post(self):
        logging.info('(POST) Uploading new file')
        # saving file in the database
        file = Files()
        file.file = db.Blob(self.request.get("file"))
        file.put()

        self.response.out.write('http://myapp.appspot.com/' + str(file.key()))

class GetFile(webapp.RequestHandler):
    def get(self, key):
        file = db.get(key)
        if file is not None:
            self.response.headers['Content-Type'] = 'application/x-bittorrent'
            self.response.out.write(file.file)
        else:
            self.response.set_status(404)

class Cleanup(webapp.RequestHandler):
    def get(self):
        '''Automatically run job (cron) to delete old records (maximum 10000)
        from Files database (records, which are older than 5 minutes)
        '''
        fiveMinutesAgoDate = datetime.datetime.now() - datetime.timedelta(minutes=5)

        q = db.GqlQuery("SELECT * FROM Files WHERE added < :1", fiveMinutesAgoDate)
        results = q.fetch(10000)
        db.delete(results)

        self.response.out.write('{"result": true}')


application = webapp.WSGIApplication(
                                     [('/upload', UploadFile),
                                      ('/file/(\w+)', GetFile),
                                      ('/cleanup', Cleanup)],
                                     debug=True)

def main():
    run_wsgi_app(application)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Is it correct? Is the approach correct? Or, shouldn't I use datastore?

**Upd**. strange, but the following code

```py
def get(self, key):
    file = db.get(key)
    if file is not None:
```

doesn't work properly if incorrect key is used.
What is wrong here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since stored files are pretty small, you should definitely go with the `datastore` as you correctly did.

Some suggestions:

1. Since you just need  the keys to delete, you should query just the keys with `SELECT __key__ FROM Files WHERE ..` saving some resources.
2. If the number of files will be huge, you could use the [mapper-api](http://code.google.com/p/appengine-mapreduce/wiki/GettingStartedInPython) to delete all of your entries; you can start mapreduce jobs from your code by using [control api](http://code.google.com/p/appengine-mapreduce/source/browse/trunk/python/src/mapreduce/control.py).
3. `/file/(\w+)` does not catch every base64 encoded keys for [url applications](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Base64#URL_applications), `_` and `-` are valid characters and you should match them as well with something like this `/file/([\w_-]+)`

Comment: Cron jobs have the same 10 minute time limit as any other offline task - 10 minutes. Enqueueing an individual task with an ETA to delete each blob would be a neater solution, though.

Comment: @Nick oh good to know, I was not aware of it thanks. I always thought cron-jobs calls as user-facing requests. Regarding the second part of the comment, you mean better than using the mapper-api?

Comment: Mapreduce is good for bulk updates, but here we know exactly which records need updating. Enqueueing one task per record, which deletes just that record, is straightforward and should work fine.

Comment: ...although I should add that if you run the mapreduce infrequently - such as daily - the vast majority of records will require deletion, so it would be efficient.

Comment: @Nick 5 minutes of uploaded files is a small window and I can agree that the task can be handled by a "canonical" task queue, but I'm curious about this, why are you suggesting to delete the keys one by one? Is it not more convenient and less resource consuming to delete them in batch?

Comment: It'd consume fewer resources, yes, but I don't think it's more convenient - `defer(db.delete, a_key, _countdown=300)` is all it would take to delete something in 5 minutes, which is a lot easier than setting up and scheduling mapreduces. I doubt the resources this will consume are significant, either, unless users are uploading a _lot_ of files.

Comment: ah ok thanks, it makes sense. (and this is why I've wrote _If the number of files will be huge.._)

Answer (score 3):

From a cursory look over the code, your approach should work.  However you may want to use the [Blobstore](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/python/blobstore/overview.html) instead of blobs in the datastore, depending on your needs and the size of the files you're trying to serve.

Comment: What is the advantage of blobstore usage? Files are ~20Kb.

Comment: If your files are 20kb, then stick with the datastore.  Here is a quick overview of blobstore vs datastore.  The pros of the blobstore:  1)  You can store much larger files; datastore entities are limited to 1MB each.  2)  It's cheaper; blobstore quota is roughly 3x cheaper than the high-replication datastore.  However, the cons:  1)  You must have billing enabled; you get 1GB free, but your app must have it enabled to use blobstore.  2)  Blobstore does not support namespaces.

Comment: Namespaces are more or less irrelevant to the blobstore, since it issues opaque keys - just make sure you store the keys in datastore entities in the relevant namespace.

Comment: Shouldn't I use memcache instead? Then I will be able to avoid usage of that cron-cleanup job.

Comment: I'm not clear on your meaning, what cron cleanup job?  Also what do you need the memcache for?  Memcache is just that--a cache.  If you're saying to use it as the sole storage of your files, that is a very very bad idea.

Comment: @waffle, ok, `datastore` should be used instead of `memcache`. With regards to the deletion of old file - I use cron job currently to delete files (it calls `Cleanup`). It is run each 10 minutes.